# Paypal V.zero get shipping info

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm trying to obtain the users shipping info from a v.zero check out in php.  I have a successful result object returned $result->success = true;

I can get the id like: 
$result->transaction->id

But I can't figure out how to get the users shipping info?  How is this done with v.zero? thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can use the [`shippingDetails`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#shipping_details) property of `transaction` to access the shipping information that was used to process that transaction. For example: `$result->transaction->shippingDetails`.

From the [Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#shipping_details):

> The shipping address details used to process this transaction. If shipping address was stored in the Vault, then the `shippingDetails` is a snapshot of the address in the Vault at the time the transaction was created.